# Can't properly define handler method to close main program frame and dialog pop-up

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

to be honest I'm only just learning GUI on Java and currently learning AWT only, no SWING yet. I don't seem to quite understand how to use listeners or containers yet and I managed to close the main program frame window when pressing X button, but I can't achieve the same for my pop-up Dialog error message. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dialog.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class AWTAccum extends Frame implements KeyListener {

    private Label lbl1;
    private Label lbl2;
    private TextField tf1;
    private TextField tf2;
    private int sum = 0;
    private Dialog pop;

    public AWTAccum() {

        setTitle("AWT Accumulator");
        setSize(300, 150);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        lbl1 = new Label("Enter an integer");
        lbl2 = new Label("Accumulated sum is");
        tf1 = new TextField("", 10);
        tf2 = new TextField("0", 10);

        tf1.setEditable(true);
        tf2.setEditable(false);

        add(lbl1);
        add(tf1);
        add(lbl2);
        add(tf2);

        tf1.addKeyListener(this);

        pop = new Dialog(this, "Error", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        Label msg = new Label("You can enter integers only.");
        pop.setSize(200, 100);
        pop.setVisible(false);
        pop.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pop.add(msg);
        pop.setResizable(false);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent w) {
                if (w.getWindow().equals(this)) {
                    dispose();
                    System.exit(1);
                } else if (w.getWindow().equals(pop)) {
                    pop.dispose();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new AWTAccum();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            try {

                sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
                tf1.setText("");
                tf2.setText(Integer.toString(sum));

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                pop.setVisible(true);

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Help strongly appreciated. Also if somebody wants to, please explain to me why a Dialog needs an owner frame and wether it needs to be the main class frame or if I make another frame class wouldn't that be like a window inside another? Dialog is confusing me a lot since I thought I could just create an instance of it but its showing me errors unless it's created inside a frame type class. I thought it was a top level container by its own.

Comment: *"currently learning AWT only"* There is no good reason to be learning to use AWT components. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I usually work with swing, so I may be wrong. But I think you need to set the popup to be focusable, and then add a key listener to the popup.

```
pop.setFocusable(true);
this.addKeyListener(pop);
```

Also you should really be learning swing instead of awt, awt is really outdated.

Comment: Hi! my code finally worked, thanks to a hint you gave me, it wasn't precisely this.addKeyListener(pop); but pop.addWindowListener( ... personalized Adapter code because im not implementing the whole interface). And the pop.setFocusable() wasn't needed, I'll show you the code working as an answer to my own post.

Btw I know AWT will probably de deprecated soon but I just wanna go step by step, that way I can appreciate the improvements made in SWING.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dialog.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class AWTAccum extends Frame implements KeyListener {

    private Label lbl1;
    private Label lbl2;
    private TextField tf1;
    private TextField tf2;
    private int sum = 0;
    private Dialog pop;

    public AWTAccum() {

        setTitle("AWT Accumulator");
        setSize(300, 150);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        lbl1 = new Label("Enter an integer");
        lbl2 = new Label("Accumulated sum is");
        tf1 = new TextField("", 10);
        tf2 = new TextField("0", 10);

        tf1.setEditable(true);
        tf2.setEditable(false);

        add(lbl1);
        add(tf1);
        add(lbl2);
        add(tf2);

        tf1.addKeyListener(this);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent w) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });

        pop = new Dialog(this, "Error", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        Label msg = new Label("You can enter integers only.");
        pop.setSize(200, 100);
        pop.setVisible(false);
        pop.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pop.add(msg);
        pop.setResizable(false);
        //pop.setFocusable(true);

        pop.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent w) {
                pop.dispose();

            }
        });      

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new AWTAccum();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            try {

                sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
                tf1.setText("");
                tf2.setText(Integer.toString(sum));

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                pop.setVisible(true);

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```